# UIImage from UIImagePickerController too large

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I get an image from the Iphone 5 camera with

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:   (NSDictionary *)info {
    UIImage *image = [info objectForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];
    ...
    }
```

According to the Debug Navigator the image size must be about 30MB.
After the method is finished (when nothing is done in the method), these 30MB become free again.
But, when I want to save the image with this line of code in the method above:

```
self.myImage = [UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)];
```

The 30MB stay in memory. I understand that there must be some memory used for the image, but not 30MB. I thought I decreased the original image size with UIImageJPEGRepresentation()?

Is there another way to decrease the file size of an image, without changing height and width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[UIImage imageWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)]
```

This line of code actually does nothing to the memory footprint of the image. It simply causes it to be lower quality due to JPEG representation.

The only way you can lower the memory footprint, assuming you need to display the image, is to crop/scale it to a smaller size.

If you do not need to display the image, you can store the image in JPEG format by storing the return NSData returned by UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8)]

Comment: Thank you. This means, if I save the NSData to disk and restore a UIImage from the NSData it becomes 30MB again, although the NSDate beeing just a few MB?

Comment: You are correct, the NSData holds the JPEG compression of the image, but in order to show it, it will uncompress it back to 30MB. Think of JPEG as a zip file, you need to unzip to access the image